# Performance issues while DELETE operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a simple delete statement like this:

```
DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID='Something'
```

This deletes only one record for that ID, which is taking more than a minute since `MY_TABLE` is referenced by a Foreign Key created on another table that has around 40 millions records and the DELETE operation checks existence of this ID in that large table.

One way is to drop/re-create this Foreign Key, but this DELETE operation gets performed by the application users and I can not just drop/re-create this FK on the fly unless it could have been an off-hours operation.

Can anyone help?

Comment: create a non-clustered index on the foreign key

Comment: @Vikas verma,Created index for columns using in where clause

Comment: Check for any triggers or on delete clauses on this table.

Comment: run the delete command on the SQL Server Management Studio and check the Execution Plan. It will show you the relationships/triggers that cause the delay.

Comment: Using an int of bigint as ID would be better. With index off course.

Answer (score 0):

So there's an excellent SO question that you can refer
<kbd>[SQL delete performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630543/sql-delete-performance?rq=1)</kbd>.

Apart from the suggestions on the question like

> Possible causes:
>
> 1) cascading delete operations
>
> 2) trigger(s)
>
> 3) the type of your primary key column is something other than an
>   integer, thereby forcing a type conversion on each pk value to do the
>   comparison. this requires a full table scan.
>
> 4) does your query really end in a dot like you posted it in the
>   question? if so, the number may considered to be a floating point
>   number instead of an integer, thereby causing a type conversion
>   similar to 3)
>
> 5) your delete query is waiting for some other slow query to release a
>   lock

**Importantly**:

1. We should definitely look into triggers. You should try to do away with triggers if there are any.
2. Also try to see if there are index on the FK in the other large table.
3. See if you can convert your query to a CASCADE delete to deleting from large table and then deleting from the `MY_TABLE` like in query below

   `DELETE FROM LARGE_TABLE WHERE LT.FK IN (SELECT PK FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID='Something')
   GO
   DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID='Something'`

   Also see the performance plan for first query on `LARGE_TABLE`.
4. You should try to replace `WHERE ID='Something'` with an `INT` key operation like `WHERE anotherID=34`. Basically instead of using a string in WHERE try to use integers for deletion. It is hard to believe that `ID` column in varchar. You should have a Primary KEY clustered indexed column in `MY_Table`, and use this key in WHERE clause.
5. Another way to improve performance is to drop the FK contraint between tables. You can always periodically do garbage deletion from `LARGE_TABLE` followed by Index rebuilding.
6. Another simpler way is to introduce mapping table between these tables. Where say a table named Map_My_Table_Large_Table exists which keeps following columns (FK column from My_Table, FK column from Large_Table). You can shift your CASCADE delete to this table.